# Formatting database dates variables in php

Tags: php, mysql

i'm writing a search query in a php application where the query its meant to bring up results which matches with the date the user inputs. From the webpage the date sent pattern looks like this `"2015/12/17"` and the database also store dates as this `"2015-12-17 15:30:12"`.

Now i want to format the query so that it works with the date format the user sends so i can get the results i want.

```
SELECT *
FROM payments 
WHERE pay_date BETWEEN rdate1 AND rdate2
```

How do i format the rdate1 and rdate2

Comment: in which format do you want to change?

Comment: And you need to sanitise

Answer (score 1):

use str_to_date

```
str_to_date(rdate1,'%Y/%m/%d')
```

try this query :-

```
SELECT *
FROM payments 
WHERE pay_date BETWEEN str_to_date(rdate1,'%Y/%m/%d') 
AND str_to_date(rdate2,'%Y/%m/%d')
```

Comment: i used it but it didn't work out. still brings out blank results

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's built in function `str_replace`

```
$var = "2015/12/17";
$var = str_replace($var,'//','-');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_format(pay_date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```